# Where can I get or see the Clipboard images and text in Windows 11?

Tags: filesystems, windows-11

I am aware that ``Windows + V" Brings up the Clipboard History. But I want to know *where* in the files are those images saved. Where can I directly access and *see* those images? Is there a specific folder where these images and text from the clipboard are stored?